# DataGridView Button Column text Can not be added

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 2 Buttons one to increase and one to decrease 
i want to add text to the button like for the `increase one (+) to decrease one (-)`
i tried to add it in the daragridview `Tasks Edit Columns Text Field` but it did not show anything so i tried with code 
my increase button name is "Add"
so i typed this on the cellpainting event

```
Add.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            Add.Text = "+";
```

still did not work 
how can i add text to the button or images

Comment: You can use buttonColumn.HeaderText
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue?view=netframework-4.8

or use e.Graphics.DrawString() if you are coding inside cellpainting event.

Comment: @christoissac thanks i found an error on the form name 

{this.Name = "Market";}
it says can not convert to string when i delete the line it worked 
but every time i do an action that error pop up again

Comment: just delete the bin and obj folders then compile it once.. otherwise, edit the query with exact error trace.